# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ceil'

Tags: tensorflow, pip, installation, onnx

I have installed the module onnx_tf from this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#installing_from_sources).

After that when I am verifying the installation as `python -c "import onnx_tf"` I am encountering the following error. How do I resolve it? Thank you

```
testuser@testuser:~$ python -c "import onnx_tf"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onnx_tf/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import frontend
  File "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onnx_tf/frontend.py", line 18, in <module>
    from onnx_tf.common.handler_helper import get_all_frontend_handlers
  File "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onnx_tf/common/handler_helper.py", line 5, in <module>
    from onnx_tf.handlers.backend import *  # noqa
  File "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/ceil.py", line 10, in <module>
    @tf_func(tf.ceil)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ceil'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your tensorflow version

```
pip show tensorflow
```

If it's 2.x, you may need to change to older version.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14
```

or if you are using a cpu...

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

Answer (score 1):

The following resolved this issue for me:

1. pip uninstall onnx-tf
2. pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow.git
3. pip install tensorflow-addons

(Using TensorFlow 2.3 and Python 3.8)